# Nombre de ruta similar a Laravel en Node js

Tags: laravel, nodejs

Estuve buscando por todos lados y no encuentro la forma de replicar algo que sucede con el freamwork laravel en NodeJs

En laravel se puede hacer lo siguiente

```
Route::get('user/profile', function () { 
  // Codigo 
})->name('profile');
```

Lo cual te permite asignarle un nombre a la ruta, lo que te simplifica el día de mañana si por alguna razón se quiere cambiar el URL por ejemplo a 'usuario/perfil'

En NodeJs defino la url en el archivo de rutas para luego definir la acción en el controlador
router.get('/create', productController.create);

Hay alguna forma de replicar lo de Laravel en NodeJs.
Se me ocurrio definir un objeto literal en el controlador con las rutas para después pasarlo a la vista por lo que podria modificar el url tranquilamente.

El problema es que en mi archivo EJS tengo que llamar la ruya de la siguiente manera

```
href="/products/edit/<%= product.id %>"
```

Explicitamente estoy poniendo /products y lo que quiero es el dia de mañana poder cambiar a /productos si tenes que editar todas las vistas donde se encuentre este link

Comment: Creo que podrías ver esta librería, aunque no la doy como una repuesta porque la última actualización fue en 2019 https://github.com/alubbe/named-routes a demás te recomendaría editar tu pregunta, no explicas bien el funcionamiento de name() lo cual puede ser confuso para los que no hallan usado laravel y tienes algunos errores de ortografía.

Comment: pero estás usando node como api o como ssr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, creo que es inexacto preguntar por la equivalencia entre el router de Laravel y el de NodeJS. Tú te refieres acaso al router de Express, pero las rutas se declaran casi exactamente igual en [Fastify](https://github.com/fastify/fastify#example) o [Koa](https://github.com/hemanth/koa-rest/blob/master/app.js), por nombrar algunos.

Con respecto a tu duda, si lo que quieres es tener un manejo central de rutas, tal que cambiando su estructura en un solo lugar se propague el cambio a toda la aplicación, incluyendo las vistas, EJS es muy flexible a la hora de incluir helpers e incluso declarar funciones dentro de la plantilla (Cosa que acá no vamos a hacer). *Nunca he usado EJS (me acostumbré a handlebars y twig) así que lo siguiente es una solución improvisada.*

##### Solución Improvisada

Se me ocurre por ejemplo tener un objeto a modo de diccionario donde las llaves sean el nombre de la ruta. Por ejemplo:

```
cost rutas = {
  profile:'/profile/'
  logout:'/user/logout'
}
```

Entonces en la aplicación declararías las rutas como

```
app.get(rutas.profile, Controller.xxx)
```

y en la plantilla, pasando las rutas como variable local

```
ejs.render('Ir al perfil: <%= rutas.profile %>')
```

sin embargo esta solución es muy limitada porque tus rutas con seguridad tienen parámetros y es necesario interpolarlos (en EJS) y dejarlos expresados como placeholders (en express o el router que uses). Se me ocurre entonces que en vez de un diccionario de nombres y rutas estáticas, debiese ser un diccionario donde los valores fuesen un objeto con la forma

```
 { handler: ejs.compile(...), default:{...} }
```

Por ejemplo

```
const rutas= {
  perfil: {
     handler: ejs.compile("/profile/<%= id %>"),
     default: {
      id: ':id'
     }
  }
}
```

Con este objeto yo puedo hacerme una función helper que recibiendo el nombre de la ruta sepa invocar al handler con los parámetros que yo le pase o bien con los parámetros por defecto para esa ruta. Esa función sería algo como:

```
function routeFor(routeName, parameters) {
  // si la ruta no existe, devuelvo literalmente routeName
  if (!rutas[routeName]) return routeName
  return rutas[routeName].handler(parameters || rutas[routeName].default || {})
}
```

De manera que `routeFor('profile',{id:1})` retorna `/profile/1` mientras que `routeFor('profile')` retorna `/profile/:id` (porque usa el valor por defecto que es `{id:':id'}`)

###### Demo

```js
const rutas = {
  perfil: {
    handler: ejs.compile("/profile/<%= id %>"),
    default: {
      id: ':id'
    }
  },
  home: {
    handler: ejs.compile("/home"),
    default: {}
  }
}

function routeFor(routeName, parameters) {
  if (!rutas[routeName]) return routeName
  return rutas[routeName].handler(parameters || rutas[routeName].default || {})

}
console.log(`en express: '${routeFor('perfil')}'`)
console.log(`home es: '${routeFor('home',{a:1,b:4})}' y dan igual los parámetros extra`)
console.log(`en EJS:     '${routeFor('perfil',{id:1})}'`)

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ejs.render(
  `<pre>El link para perfil 5 es: "<%= routeFor("perfil",{id:5}); %>"
Pero en express pondría solamente 
"app.get(routeFor('perfil'), Controller.xxx)" que es
app.get('<%= routeFor('perfil') %>', Controller.xxx)
  </pre>`, {
    routeFor
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/mde/ejs/releases/download/v3.1.6/ejs.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Con eso andando, tanto el router como la renderización de la vista obedecen a lo que sea que declares en el handler del objeto de rutas.

Si cambias

```
const rutas= {
  perfil: {
     handler: ejs.compile("/mi_cuenta/<%= id %>"),
     default: {
      id: ':id'
     }
  }
}
```

Eso se propaga tanto al router como a la vista... **pero ojo**, porque si cambias los nombres de los parámetros

```
const rutas= {
  perfil: {
     handler: ejs.compile("/mi_cuenta/<%= user_id %>"),
     default: {
      user_id: ':user_id'
     }
  }
}
```

Ya no sirve invocarla como `routeFor('perfil', {id:1})`. Ahora sería `routeFor('perfil', {user_id:1})`. El controller a su vez recibirá el parámetro como `user_id` en vez de `id`. Seguramente es innecesario hacer esta salvedad, pero mejor mencionarlo.